# a problem about ffi function call in openresty

Tags: luajit, openresty

I have some code writen in c, and I wraped these code by lua ffi. When I call my lua file directly by luajit,It works fine.but when I call it from openresty, openresty got an error log: `exit on signal 11`

nginx version: openresty/1.15.8.1
operating system: debian 9
system luajit: LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3 -- Copyright (C) 2005-2017 Mike Pall.
openresty luajit: LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3 -- Copyright (C) 2005-2017 Mike Pall.

I write a test file to show the different result of two platform

```lua
-- filename: gateway/test.lua
local ffi = require "ffi"

ffi.cdef [=[
    typedef struct _TrigxNode {
        int val;
        struct _TrigxNode *char_nodes[64];
        struct _TrigxNode *rgx_next;
        int rgx_raw_len;
        void *re;
        char *rgx;
    } TrigxNode;
    TrigxNode *create_trigx_node();
    void trigx_insert(TrigxNode *root, const char *word, int len_word, int val);
    int trigx_search(TrigxNode *root, const char *word, int len_word);
    void trigx_free(TrigxNode *root);
   ]=];

local C = ffi.load("trigx_tree")

local node = C.create_trigx_node()
C.trigx_insert(node, '/menu/', 6, 10)
local result = C.trigx_search(node, '/menu/', 6)
if ngx ~= nil then
    --  test in openresty
    ngx.say("result: " .. result)
else
    -- test in luajit
    print("result: " .. result)
end
return
```

```
http {

    init_worker_by_lua_block {
        local uuid = require 'resty.jit-uuid'
        uuid.seed()
        local verbose = false
        if verbose then
            local dump = require "jit.dump"
            dump.on(nil, "./jit.log")
        else
            local v = require "jit.v"
            v.on("./jit.log")
        end
        require "resty.core"
    }

    server {
        listen 9090;

        location / {
            content_by_lua_file "gateway/test.lua";
        }

        location /login {
            default_type 'application/json';
            content_by_lua_file 'gateway/login.lua';
        }

        location /wechat-callback {
            content_by_lua_file 'gateway/wechat_identify.lua';
        }

    }
}
```

when i call the ffi function directly by luajit, `luajit -i gateway/test.lua`,I can see the right result are printed

but when i try to call test.lua in nginx worker by `curl 'localhost:9090/abc'`,error occured

[two](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/30937220/61273379-eef1a100-a7db-11e9-91ae-2ded27727b88.png) [pictures](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/30937220/61273602-7f2fe600-a7dc-11e9-88bf-d763d5d7a383.png) show the detail of result

Comment: the result of luajit directly call the test file [link](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/30937220/61273379-eef1a100-a7db-11e9-91ae-2ded27727b88.png)

Comment: ok um why do you abuse bold instead of `code` for code, and why the pictures instead of just copypasting it to us in code blocks? that said `signal 11` is SIGSEGV (segmentation fault), which means you tried to access memory outside of your range. since you're not actually manipulating any pointers yourself it's either in whatever trigx is or nginx.

Answer (score -1):

I use calloc rather malloc in source file then problem solved.but still can't find out why this can work in luajit

Comment: neither `calloc` nor `malloc` are anywhere in your source file (as far as you've shown), so we can't help you with that.